# How to set up Bootstrap structure for footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am having trouble seting up HTML5 structure in Bootstrap 4 grid system to look like attached image. It needs to look like top image if device (phone, phablet or tablet is in portrait mode) and bottom if they are in landscape mode.

Images
[img 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rp5bof5ea9mrut7/Capture.PNG?dl=0)

[img 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5n8idl7maeewoz1/Capture%202.PNG?dl=0)

Code
https://jsfiddle.net/tokdwvkg/

```
<footer><!-- Code is too long to post, so see jsfiddle --></footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use divs inside the footer just like anywhere else on an HTML page.  You can make rows, use the columnar system, and even (though I don't recommend this) theoretically put five million three dimensional tables in there.  The footer is simply a specially-named div.

Comment: I know that, if you look at js fiddle I have my vision of how it should look, but I can't make it work.

Comment: if it's landscape, wouldn't you want the footer clean across the bottom so that it's not a black lump in the center?  And that's from a design standpoint, not to mention how much easier it'd be to code EDIT: Never mind, that's the footer of the thing you're using to share the pictures....I'm stupid.

Comment: where on the page do you want this to be?  Left, right, center?

Comment: That is the footer, I know how would be easier from design point but I have a client who has specific needs. The first image is how footer should look like in portrait on all devices, the second image is if they are in landscape how they should look.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I got it working the way you want, check the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/o6uf9hq4/

```
<footer class="footer__wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
          <h5 class="footer__contact-us-header footer__text--underline">
                  CONTACT OUR <br>
                  EXCLUSIVE AGENTS AT
                </h5>
          <div class="footer__line footer__line--pl10"></div>
          <h3 class="footer__contact-us-number">‎646-846-0954</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="footer__name-wrapper col-sm-6 col-md-2">
          <h3 class="footer__name footer__text--underline">BRAD COHEN</h3>
          <div class="footer__line"></div>
          <p class="footer__name-title">
            Senior Director<br>
            <a href="mailto:bc@ecretail.com" class="footer__name-link">
              bc@ecretail.com
            </a>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="footer__name-wrapper col-sm-6 col-md-2">
          <h3 class="footer__name footer__text--underline">JACOB TZFANYA</h3>
          <div class="footer__line"></div>
          <p class="footer__name-title">Senior Director<br>
            <a href="mailto:jt@ecretail.com" class="footer__name-link">
              jt@ecretail.com
            </a>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="footer__name-wrapper col-sm-6 col-md-2">
          <h3 class="footer__name footer__text--underline">JON KAMALI</h3>
          <div class="footer__line"></div>
          <p class="footer__name-title">Director<br>
            <a href="mailto:jk@ecretail.com" class="footer__name-link">
              jk@ecretail.com
            </a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row justify-content-end">

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
          <div class="footer__sponsor-logo-wrapper">
            <img class="footer__sponsor-logo" src="img/terreno-logo.png" alt="#">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
          <div class="footer__address-wrapper">
            <img src="img/ec-logo-footer.svg" alt="" class="footer__logo">
            <p class="footer__ec-contact">
              355 Lexington Avenue,<br>
              New York, NY 10017<br>
              easternconsolidated.com<br>
              T: 212.499.7700; <br>
              F: 212.499.7718
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
</footer>
<html>
```

Here are a some guidelines to use the grid system extracted from the [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment):

- Containers provide a means to center and horizontally pad your site’s contents. Use `.container` for a responsive pixel width or `.container-fluid` for width: 100% across all viewport and device sizes.
- Rows are wrappers for columns. Each column has horizontal padding (called a gutter) for controlling the space between them. This padding is then counteracted on the rows with negative margins. This way, all the content in your columns is visually aligned down the left side.
- In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and only columns may be immediate children of rows.
- Thanks to flexbox, grid columns without a specified width will automatically layout as equal width columns. For example, four instances of .col-sm will each automatically be 25% wide from the small breakpoint and up. See the auto-layout columns section for more examples.
- Column classes indicate the number of columns you’d like to use out of the possible 12 per row. So, if you want three equal-width columns across, you can use .col-4.
- Column widths are set in percentages, so they’re always fluid and sized relative to their parent element.
- Columns have horizontal padding to create the gutters between individual columns, however, you can remove the margin from rows and padding from columns with .no-gutters on the .row.
- To make the grid responsive, there are five grid breakpoints, one for each responsive breakpoint: all breakpoints (extra small), small, medium, large, and extra large.
- Grid breakpoints are based on minimum width media queries, meaning they apply to that one breakpoint and all those above it (e.g., .col-sm-4 applies to small, medium, large, and extra large devices, but not the first xs breakpoint)
- You can use predefined grid classes (like .col-4) or Sass mixins for more semantic markup.